# How to do a load test on a server?

Tags: node.js, performance, server

I have a server on which is running an application, consisting essentially of a drupal website that have on back-end a little application in node.js. The website contains some games and the application allow user to play, managing user matching to play together to a game, for example.

Now, this website is growing and i need to know, essentially, how many people can use the website without make it crash.

How can i measure the load that the server can manage? And, really, what i must expect happening when the load is too much?

EDIT: the server is running ubuntu 12.04

Comment: have you looked at [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/loadtest)?

Comment: no, i don't know it. I'll try!